# parsing xml doc with Javascript

Tags: javascript

hey guys.. i was wondering what the best way to go about getting a node from an xml doc into a javascript variable would be?  i dont really want to use jquery because i believe that i wont have too..  so far i have:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","sc2cash.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
```

but now how i select the nodes?  thanks

Comment: not sure there's any good way of parsing XML in js without an external library. when you use ajax it's not typical to send the data as xml, usually it's sent as json

Comment: well maybe you can help me understand how it works with jquery?

Comment: AJAX stands for Asynchronous Javascript and XML, and until the last 2 years or so, it was totally commonplace to use XML instead of json, and to do it without a library.  The more time I spend on SO, the more it feels like writing plain old javascript like this has become a lost art :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse the returned XML using DOM manipulators.  We'll need more information about the XML returned to be more specific.

```
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

// For example - get "person" tags if there were any
var people = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("person");

// All child nodes under the first person
var children = people[0].childNodes;
```

Comment: is  there any way to do something like this? xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("person")[0];

Comment: whoa, other shawn here, had no idea you could do that